# Questions to be reviewed based on reviewer's expertise

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review

Most *probably*, our SO moderators will be *little upset* to see this question. Apology in advance. There is a considerable amount of reviews/edits to be done daily. However when reviewing a question, in terms of English we may notice if it's out of topic. That to say the question is obviously ambiguous/talking totally something else than the title/body -vise versa.. But in terms of technology domain, only a person familiar with a particular technology is able to correctly mark a question as "off topic" or "not constructive".

But often, it seems that when one marks a question off topic/non-constructive, some follows the norm blindly and mark it without much consideration.

Thus is it possible to let users to review and mark questions based on their expertise/specialized tags/questions/answers? This could improve the quality of question reviewing.

Comment: Yup. I could see the discussion. @BradLarson seems to provide a good insight. And even yourself for the question tagged on top.